I am having "Trouble Loading Stake" in Phantom Wallet
Hello I am having a problem in mobile wallet where I am getting a "TROUBLE LOADING STAKE" message. After 3 or four tries it eventually loads. Stake is there and funds are safe but this needs to be corrected. Please help.
